# How to upgrade from Python 2 to python 3 on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-linux-2

I created a new AL2 EC2. I see Python 2 is already installed.

How can I upgrade this to Python 3 WITHOUT using virtualenv? I would like to maintain ONLY ONE version of Python.

Comment: I'm going to guess something like "yum remove python" and "yum install python3". Those commands might not work but it's worth a go. Otherwise if Python3 isn't available for AL2 you can add a Python repo or move to an OS with more widely available packages like Ubuntu.

Comment: @Tim You can't because `yum` depends on `python`. I don't think there is a sane reason to want what the OP is requesting, anyway. Like many other distros, Amazon Linux calls Python 2 `python` and Python 3 `python3` so there is no confusion if you leave Python 2 on your system.

Comment: Interesting @tripleee. Guess the answer then is don't uninstall python2, just additionally install python3.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: it may break `yum`, because `yum` uses python2!!!**

Make sure you don't have it already:

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python2-config  /usr/bin/python3.7   /usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3         /usr/bin/python3.7m
```

if you do have and don't like to use `python3` instead of just `python`, then

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
python --version
Python 3.7.10
```

You might also want:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```